# Lipschitz map from $L^p$ to $L^q$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lipschitz-functions

Let $1<p<q\leq\infty$ and $J=[0,T)$ for some $T>0$. The measure space we consider is the usual: $J$ together with the appropriate Borel-Sigma-Algebra and the Lebesgue measure. Can you give me an example of a Lipschitz map from $L^p(J)$ to $L^q(J)$?

It is not hard to find a Lipschitz map from $L^p(J)$ to $L^p(J)$ or from $L^q(J)$ to $L^p(J)$ (since $J$ is finite we have $L^q(J)\subset L^p(J)$ with analogue norm estimate). But I don't see an easy example for my situation. The map may also be only locally Lipschitz.

Finally, the definitions I am working with:

1) Let $(A,\textrm{d}_A)$ and $(B,\textrm{d}_B)$ be metric spaces. $f:A\rightarrow B$ is called Lipschitz continuous if there is a constant $M\geq 0$ such that $\textrm{d}_B(f(a_1),f(a_2))\leq M\textrm{d}_A(a_1,a_2)$ for all $a_1,a_2\in A.$

2) $f:A\rightarrow B$ is called locally Lipschitz continuous if for every $a\in A$ there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $a$ such that $f\vert_U$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Are you looking for linear Lipschitz continuous functions or just Lipschitz continuous functions? Any constant map is Lipschitz. The zero map is linear and Lipschitz so you have to say what more conditions are required on the map.

Comment: No, it does not need to be linear. Do you know of any non-constant maps with the desired property?

Answer (score 0):

The map
$$
\phi:L^p(J)\to L^q(J)\\
f \mapsto 0
$$
is globally Lipschitz continuous.